# Youtube API & Instagram API: Is there a way to work around constraints (liking comments, linking accounts) with social media management tools?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, instagram, instagram-api, tiktok-api

My company is using swat.io for managing Instagram, YouTube and TikTok. There are several constraints that may be routed in the app's APIs? For example, swat.io does not allow to like comments on YouTube or Insta. Comments related to our YouTube content older than 30 days are not visible in swat.io. Linking other accounts is very restricted on TikTok. Can you recommend ways to work around or better tools?

Asking swat.io, searching on Google, asking Chat GPT and Google Bard